# XML represent bits in XML file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a 8-bits number, that every bit in it represent some data.

For example:

```
01101100
```

The 1st bit (`0`) - indicate some flag, the 2nd (`1`) - another flag etc.

I want to save all the data in XML file, what is the best way to do it?

This is what I have right now:

> ```
> <bit1 Description="Y axis">
>   <x1>    Y axis enabled</x1>
>   <x0>    Y axis disabled</x0>
> </bit1>
> <bit0 Description="X axis">
>   <x1>    X axis enabled</x1>
>   <x0>    X axis disabled</x0>
> </bit0>
> ```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to store the data contained in the bits, or the mapping of the bits to 'what they mean'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you understood what I asked (sorry if I wasn't clear): I want to represent a large kinds of registers, so every register can be differ (=the bit seperate variedly).

Anyway this is what I gonna do (declare how many bits is every field in the register):

```
<field>
      <name>register1</name>
      <bitOffset>14</bitOffset>
      <bitWidth>18</bitWidth> 
</field>
```

Based on idea from [here](http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/ovm/tutorial_rgm_1/).

Anyway - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that xml is the last of the concerns here. The question is how you want to model the data. If you are ok with the bit representation you should simply write the actual number (01101100 in your example). If on the contrary, as your question seems to imply, you want a more structured way of representing it, you should first of all think of, well, a structure.

For example (I'm using c for the example, any language would do), a plausible structure (logically) requiring 8 bits to be represented could be:

```
struct Flags{
    struct Axis{
        bool enabled;
        bool present;
    };
    Axis axes[3];

    bool invertAllDirections;
    bool movementsEnabled;
};
```

which could be translated into an xml having the form:

```
<Flags>
    <Axes>
        <X>
            <Enabled>False</Enabled>
            <Present>True</Present>
        </X>
        <Y>
            <Enabled>True</Enabled>
            <Present>False</Present>
        </Y>
        <Z>
            <Enabled>True</Enabled>
            <Present>True</Present>
        </Z>
    </Axes>
    <invertAllDirections>False</invertAllDirections>
    <movementsEnabled>False</movementsEnabled>
</Flags>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that neither the C nor the XML reflects the bitwise nature of the data, so its utility depends on what the purpose of the representation is.  In C, bool is typically an int that is either 0 or non-zero, while a union member:
    int varname : 1;
would accurately reflect its nature while introducing the complication of packing (#pragma pack 1) and Endianness (#if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN).  Just be aware of what you want to accomplish and whether the chosen representation is adequate for that purpose, e.g., if the data are part of a low-level message and network byte order (NBO) is assumed.